# How to interpret discrepancy between two tests

Tags: chi-squared-test

Sample size = 100.I compared scores on a scale for depression and scores on a scale for disability due to pain using Pearson. I got a positive correlation. 
Next Using cut offs for the scale, I divided patients as depressed and non depressed.  I compared mean scores on disability between two groups- depressed and non depressed patients using t test. No significant difference in mean scores. 
I used cut offs to divide patients into disabled and non disabled. I did a chi square test with this group and the depressed/ non depressed group. No significant. 
How to interpret and what to conclude? Is depression higher in the disabled (positive Pearson) or not ( negative t test and chi square) 
Please do help if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you categorize a (more or less) continuous variable you throw away information. I see no reason to categorize either of your variables.

Moreover, decisions made on the basis of statistical tests and measures are not definitive. They are only reasonable judgements about what what the world is doing. You use the information in your statistical procedures to make such judgements.

Depression and disability due to pain had a significant relationship in the subjects you measured. When you dichotomized the measures then the relationship was no longer significant. If you had a good reason to do this you should tell us what it was.

Perhaps the relationship is just weak. Perhaps your choice to dichotomize the measures was a poor one.

You have to bear in mind that you have found this relationship just once on just 100 people. You do not yet have any reason to believe your conclusion is universal. Because of the possibility of Type I Error you might even be wrong in concluding that there is a relationship between depression and disability in your study sample.

I mostly favor the interpretation that it is usually foolish to throw away useful information by categorizing variables. The results you report do not surprise me.